# Finding Difference Between 3 sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[See Problem Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBDFZ.png)

So for this problem I'm given 3 sets, of which 2 are the same and 1 is different. From what I understand, #1 is different, however I can't wrap my head around why #2 and #3 are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets see at point (3.)

$$\cap_{\lambda<0}\{\eta:0\le \eta< \lambda\}$$
fix $\lambda<0$ and take arbitrary $\eta\in I_0^{\lambda}$. Then
$\eta < \lambda$, and $\lambda<0$ gives (from transitivity of [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)) $\eta < 0$, but $\eta\in I_0^{\lambda}$, so $0\le \eta$, and $0\le \eta < 0$ is contradiction - there is no real number with such property. This means that $I_0^{\lambda} = \emptyset$ for all $\lambda < 0$, and their intersection is empty too.

Try to prove, that

1.
$\cap_{\lambda>0}\{\eta:0\le \eta< \lambda\}=\{0\}$

2.
$\cap_{\lambda\ge 0}\{\eta:0\le \eta< \lambda\}=\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that #1 and #3 are equal. Both are the empty set.

1)$\bigcap_{\lambda >0}I_{0}^{\lambda}=\{k|0\leq k<\rho, \forall\rho>0\}$=$\emptyset$.

2) $\bigcap_{\lambda >0}I_{0}^{\lambda}=\{k|0\leq k<\rho, \forall\rho\geq 0\}$=$\{0\}$.

3)$\bigcap_{\lambda >0}I_{0}^{\lambda}=\{k|0\leq k<\rho, \forall\rho<0\}$=$\emptyset$.